# Cannot resolve class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart, MPAndroidChart

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, mpandroidchart, android-library

What's going on? Got all guide but I have this error.

- Class referenced in the layout file, `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart`, was not found in the project or the libraries
- Cannot resolve class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart

Did I forget something? Does it need more implementation?

My Project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Module:

```
dependencies {


    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/fragment_verticalbarchart_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get here the error

Comment: I've checked my project and I have pretty much the same in build.gradles. Aside from my layout. I've created a custom class ChartView: LineChart, where I implemented com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart, XAxis, Entry etc. In my layout, I only use: <my.project.view.custom.ChartView />. You can also try that way.

Comment: I face the same problem, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

In `build.gradle(:app)` add this:

```
dependencies {
  //chart
  implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
  ...

}
```

And In `settings.gradle` add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
 repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
 repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // add this line
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io"} in setting Gradle and it worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding `maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}`
in setting Gradle and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

In settings.gradle add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }.
Invoking menu File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).